# Обновить свойство при вводе текста TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Приветствую!

У меня на форме есть текст бокс  :

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
         Text="{Binding TextToSend}"/>
```

и кнопка

```
<Button Content="SEND" Command="{Binding InsertMessage}"/>
```

Внутри вьюмодели есть свойство к которому текст привязан :

```
private string _texttosend { get; set; }
public string TextToSend
{
    get
    {
        return _texttosend;
    }
    set
    {
        _texttosend = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TextToSend");
    }
}
```

Команда `InsertMessage` содержит проверку связанного свойства :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_texttosend))
```

И если я нажимаю ПКМ мыши по Button то все работает как надо и текст из бокса попадает в связанное свойство. Однако, если я добавлю кнопке `IsDefault="True"` то произойдет ошибка - а именно `_texttosend == null`. Не могу понять почему так. Разница только в том, что первый раз я нажимаю на кнопку мышью а во втором случае вызываю команду через ENTER. В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger` установите в `PropertyChanged`, по умолчанию там действие по `LostFocus`, в по Enter фокус не переходит видимо

Comment: `Text="{Binding TextToSend, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` имею ввиду

Comment: И да, когда вы уже начнете форматировать код в вопросах нормально? Неужели так трудно нажать пару раз `Ctrl+K`?

Comment: @Андрей про Ctrl+K не знал, спасибо, так гораздо удобнее.

Comment: @Андрей именно то, что нужно. Оформите это как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что по умолчанию обновление источника привязки происходит по событию `LostFocus`, а при нажатии клавиши Enter фокус не покидает TextBox, поэтому источник привязки не обновляется.

Чтобы добиться нужного эффекта можно включить обновление источника привязки по событию `TextChanged`, для этого установите свойство `UpdateSourceTrigger` в значение `PropertyChanged`:

```
Text="{Binding TextToSend, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```